# How to use windows server 2012 with sql server standard on aws ec2 classic of t2 instance type?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2

When I tried to launch a new instance of Amazon Machine Image windows server 2012 R2 with SQL server standard ,I was unable to use few of the instance types like t1.micro, t2.large, t2.medium .This instance type is not recommended for your selected Amazon Machine Image.
Few of the instance types are disabled,
Can anyone know the reason behind this ?How can I use t2 instance type for my current requirement to avoid high pricing?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

The cheapest instance you can use with SQL Server as I write this is c5.large.  However if you use the AWS Console "Launch Instance" button, c5.large (and other instance types that the EC2 pricing page say are suitable for SQL Server) are unavailable, saying "Instance type is disabled" and "This instance type is not recommended for your selected AMI."

AWS support say:

> This behaviour is seen because we do not recommend instance types
>   which have less than 4 VCPU for SQL based AMI’s. Hence the instance
>   types with less than 4 VCPU’s can be seen as disabled on the console.

You can still launch these unreccomended types however.  To do this:

- Find the AMI ID of the SQL image you want to launch (you can see this from the **Launch Instance** button)
- Return to the EC2 Console
- On the left, panel, choose **Images** -> **AMIs**
- Search for the AMI ID under "Public images"
- Select the AMI and choose **Launch**
- Select your preferred instance type and continue as normal

While you *can* select something like a t2.micro instance in this manner, you'll get a compatibility error and be unable to complete the launch - you **must** use an instance type listed under the SQL section on https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

Comment: While this may have been corect. Now you can't. If you entered everything, and try to startt, you'll get a screen, that this image instance type is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

t2 instances are not available at all in EC2-Classic.

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html:

> Some instance types are not available in EC2-Classic, so you must
>   launch them in a VPC. By launching an instance in a VPC, you can
>   leverage features that are not available in EC2-Classic, such as
>   enhanced networking, assigning multiple private IP addresses to the
>   instance, and changing the security groups assigned to your instance.
>   For more information, see Instance Types Available Only in a VPC.

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html#vpc-only-instance-types:

> Instances of the following instance types are not supported in
>   EC2-Classic and must be launched in a VPC:
>
> - C4
> - M4
> - T2

That would not explain why you couldn't launch a t1.micro (unless that was a typo in your post and you meant t2.micro) in EC2-Classic, but supplying the error message you got when you tried woukd help debug.

ETA: You can launch these instance in VPC, but the error about "This instance type is not recommended for your selected Amazon Machine Image" implies you are trying to use a PV image, when only HVM AMI formats are supported for t2 instances.  https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/instance-type-matrix/